# Using Express Router to proxy non-CORS content doubles request path

Tags: proxy

There must be something obvious I am missing. I have an external record like `https/udspace.udel.edu/rest/handle/19716/28599` that is not set up for CORS, but I would like to get access to it in my application. In the past, I have set up a server to simply GET the resource and redeliver it for my application. However, I read about Node `http-proxy-middleware` and thought I'd try out a more direct proxy.

First, I could not use the `target` in the `createProxyMiddleware()` constructor because I wanted to send in the `hostname` and `path` of the desired resource like, perhaps, `http://example.com/https/udspace.udel.edu/rest/handle/19716/28599` to get the resource above.

### Relevant Code (index.js)

```js
const express = require('express')
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware')

const app = express()

app.get('/info', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('Proxy is up.');
 })

// Proxy endpoint
app.use('/https', createProxyMiddleware({
    target: "incoming",
    router: req => {
        const protocol = 'https'
        const hostname = req.path.split("/https/")[1].split("/")[0]
        const path = req.path.split(hostname)[1]
        console.log(`returning: ${protocol}, ${hostname}, ${path}`)
     return `${protocol}://${hostname}/${path}`
    },
    changeOrigin: true
 }))

 app.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
    console.log(`Starting Proxy at ${HOST}:${PORT}`);
 })
```

I was getting a `404` from the DSpace server without other information, so I knew that the request was going through, but transformed incorrectly. I tried again with an item in an S3 bucket, since AWS gives better errors and saw that my path was being duplicated:

> #### 404 Not Found
>
> Code: NoSuchKey
> Message: The specified key does not exist.
> Key: api/cookbook/recipe/0001-mvm-image/manifest.json/https/iiif.io/api/cookbook/recipe/0001-mvm-image/manifest.json

What dumb thing am I doing wrong? Is this not what this proxy is for and I need to do something else?

Comment: I think it's better to ask on StackOverflow, as it's looks like code problem

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why it wasn't SO to begin with... first question troubles.